# having problem while call java class through jsp

Tags: java, jsp

```
package com.hotles.booking.new;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionProvider {

    private static Connection con;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {

            if (con == null) {
                //driver class load
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                //create a connection..
                con = DriverManager.
                        getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel", "root", "root");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return con;
    }
}
```

i am trying to call above connection on following page.

when i try to call "con" it gives

> internal server error 500
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/new.jsp] at line [33]
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="package com.hotles.booking.new "%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <% Connection con1 =ConnectionProvider.getConnection(); %>
        
            
            
           <h1><%= con1 %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Full stack trace please. If that's not appearing you need to make it do so

Answer (score 0):

Your `page` directive's syntax is wrong, you can't specify a `package` for your JSP.

```
<%@ page import="package com.hotles.booking.new " %>
                 ^
```

Fix your `ConnectionProvider` import as

```
<%@ page import="com.hotles.booking.new.ConnectionProvider" %>
```

or to import all the classes in that package

```
<%@ page import="com.hotles.booking.new.*" %>
```

Comment: @AbdulBasit can you please update your question with full stack trace? The lines after java.lang.RuntimeException would help debug the issue. If the full stack trace isn't printing on the page check your tomcat's server log.

Comment: ok check my next question. kindly help me out with this problem sir